# In which situations would I want to call -processPendingChanges of NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: iphone, core-data

In which situations would I want to call -processPendingChanges of NSManagedObjectContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two cases where I've used `-processPendingChanges` have involved undo grouping and temporary disabling of undo.

For example, I wanted to group all Core Data actions involving the deletion of a particular item (which could lead to deletions of others or other changes to the data model), so I used code like the following:

```
[[[targetOperationController managedObjectContext] undoManager] beginUndoGrouping];
[targetOperationController deleteSelectedOperation];
[[targetOperationController managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];
[[[targetOperationController managedObjectContext] undoManager] endUndoGrouping];
```

In order to guarantee that all data model changes triggered by the actions in the `-deleteSelectedOperation` method would be grouped together, I use `-processPendingChanges` to make sure they are all registered in the undo grouping block.

You can do something similar to ignore all data model changes for the purpose of undo by replacing the undo grouping with `-disableUndoRegistration` and `-enableUndoRegistration`.

Comment: Also, for a context running on a background queue, it controls when the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification is posted, since you will not get that automatically when using `performAndWait()`.